# How to get html of element but ignoring children tags except br tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

```
<div class="test"> Div Text lorem ipsum <br> lorem ipsum <p class="some_class">Paragraph Content <br> tag and again child nested in it <span> span content</span></p></div>.
```

I want to get html of div element. Here is tricky part, If i use .html() this will also include children tags which is `<p class="some_class">....<span>...</span>...</p>` I only need br tag. How can I achieve that.

final output should look like:

**Div Text lorem ipsum `<br>` lorem ipsum Paragraph content `<br>` tag and again child nested in it span content**

Comment: you're gonna have to parse the results, and as parsing html is a bad idea (html is not a structured language, which makes it very hard to parse or lookup with regular expressions), i would suggest going a different route

Comment: Why do you want only `<br>` tags?. If you need only text present inside `div`, you can use `innerText` which gives `\n` in place of `<br>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only text present inside any element, you can use `innerText` but you mentioned you required `<br>` tag in a result. So you can use `innerText` first, then replace line feed (`\n`) with `<br>` tag.

```js
var divtext = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].innerText;
console.log(divtext);
console.log(divtext.replaceAll('\n', '<br>'));
```

```html
<div class="test"> Div Text lorem ipsum <br> lorem ipsum <p class="some_class">Paragraph Content <br> tag and again child nested in it <span> span content</span></p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JavaScript (while/for) loop.

Here's a live example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Get Children Content with br tag</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="test"> Div Text lorem ipsum <br> lorem ipsum <p class="some_class">Paragraph Content <br> tag and again child nested in it <span> span content</span></p></div>.
  </body>
  <script>
    //   get all the content of the  div tag
    let test = document.getElementById("test");
    let testData = test.innerHTML;

    let finalText = "";

    // this variable will decide to capture the lettes when captured in loop.
    let capture = true;

    // starting to over all the cahracter in the text content
    for (let i = 0; i < testData.length; i++) {
      let recursive = false;
      if (
        testData.charAt(i) == "<" &&
        testData.charAt(i + 1) == "b" &&
        testData.charAt(i + 2) == "r"
      ) {
        //   if <br> tag is receved skip 4 char and increment the i value
        capture = true;
        recursive = true;
      } else if (testData.charAt(i) == "<") {
        //   if < is found stop capturing
        capture = false;
      } else if (testData.charAt(i) == ">") {
        //   if > is found start  capturing but skip this iteration
        capture = true;
      }

      //   main capturing code
      if (capture) {
        if (testData.charAt(i) != ">") {
          finalText = finalText + testData.charAt(i);
        }
        if (recursive) {
          finalText =
            finalText +
            testData.charAt(i + 1) +
            testData.charAt(i + 2) +
            testData.charAt(i + 3);
          i = i + 3;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(finalText);
  </script>
</html>
```